# R loop over a list

Tags: r, for-loop

Hi I'm new here and also quite new to R.
Would be great if anyone could please help me here.
I'm trying to make a for loop to get the desired output but a little struggling at the moment.

Let's suppose I have a table below:

```
> d
  names    variables            value
1 colour   c(red, blue)         10    
2 colour   c(yellow, blue)      32    
3 colour   c(green, red, pink)  81    
4 colour   c(pink, purple)      14
5 shape    c(circle, triangle)  5
6 shape    c(rectangle)         31
7 .....
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a for loop going over the variables for each name.
If a target variable for each name exist, then set the original value to be 0 and make a duplicated row with value taking the negative value of the original value.

As an example, let's say our target variable for colour is 'red'.
What I want the output to look like is:

```
> d1
  names    variables            value
1 colour   c(red, blue)         0    
2 colour   c(yellow, blue)      32    
3 colour   c(green, red, pink)  0    
4 colour   c(pink, purple)      14
5 colour1  c(red, blue)         -10
6 colour2  c(green, red, pink)  -81       
7 shape    c(circle, triangle)  5
8 shape    c(rectangle)         31
7 .....
```

I hope I'm making sense.
Any help or comments would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution with Base R only, using TarJae's construction of the data, for a dataframe `x`:

```
# Create a vector with the row indeces that contain the target string:
target <- grep( 'red', x[ , 2 ] )
# Put these rows away in a separate data.frame:
stash <- x[ target, ]
# Set the value of the original rows to `0`
x[ target, 3 ] <- 0
# Set the values in the separated rows to their negative value 
stash[ , 3 ] <- stash[ , 3 ] * -1
# Modify `names` as desired:
for( i in 1 : length( stash[ , 1 ] ) ) 
    stash[ i, 1 ] <-  paste( stash[ i, 1 ], i, sep = "" )

# Insert the modified data (supposes that the dataframe is expected 
# to be sorted on the first column):
x <- rbind( x, stash )
x <- x[ order(x[ 1 ] ),  ]
```

That gives you

```
> x
     names           variables value
1   colour        c(red, blue)     0
2   colour     c(yellow, blue)    32
3   colour c(green, red, pink)     0
4   colour     c(pink, purple)    14
11 colour1        c(red, blue)   -10
31 colour2 c(green, red, pink)   -81
5    shape c(circle, triangle)     5
6    shape        c(rectangle)    31
```

This works as well if you replace `'red'` with `'blue'` or with `'rectangle'`. For the extended question in your comment: One could create a vector with the targets (such as `c( "red", "triangle" )`, then loop over the code above, writing each output into a list. More sample data and information about your desired output would be needed, though. As a first step, you could try:

```
crit <- c( "rectangle", "red", "blue" )     # vector with target values
y <- list()                                 # initialize receiving list
for( j in 1 : length( crit ) )
{ 
    target <- grep( crit[ j ], x[ , 2 ] )
    stash <- x[ target, ] 
    stash[ , 3 ] <- stash[ , 3 ] * -1
    # Modify `names` as desired:
    for( i in 1 : length( stash[ , 1 ] ) ) 
        stash[ i, 1 ] <-  paste( stash[ i, 1 ], ( 10 * i + j ), sep = "" )

    # write to list element instead of overwriting original dataframe
    y[[ j ]] <- rbind( x, stash )
    y[[ j ]][ target, 3 ] <- 0      # Set the value of the original rows to `0`
    y[[ j ]] <- y[[ j ]][ order( y[[ j ]][ 1 ] ),  ]
    # here, you have a list with individual dataframes for each target value
    
    # you could merge into one joint dataframe with
    z <- Reduce( function( x, y, ... ) merge( x, y, all = TRUE, ... ), y )
}
```

That produces

```
> z
      names           variables value
1    colour c(green, red, pink)     0
2    colour c(green, red, pink)    81
3    colour     c(pink, purple)    14
4    colour        c(red, blue)     0
5    colour        c(red, blue)    10
6    colour     c(yellow, blue)     0
7    colour     c(yellow, blue)    32
8  colour12        c(red, blue)   -10
9  colour13        c(red, blue)   -10
10 colour22 c(green, red, pink)   -81
11 colour23     c(yellow, blue)   -32
12    shape c(circle, triangle)     5
13    shape        c(rectangle)     0
14    shape        c(rectangle)    31
15  shape11        c(rectangle)   -31
```

and may be a good start for further work

Comment: Thank you so much vaettvhen, very helpful, much appreciate it!!

Comment: The `Reduce()` function could / should be run after finishing the loop. Result is the same, but it needs to be done only once, after the list `y` is finalised.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `tidyverse`:

1. First we use `str_detect` from `stringr` package (it is in tidyverse) to identify those rows with `red` ind variables.
2. Then we add 1 and 2 (=row_number) to `names` and multiple `value` by -1 to get the negative values.
3. we use `bind_rows` from `dplyr` package (it is in tidyverse) to bind to original dataframe.
4. Then we use an `ifelse` statement to set variables red to 0 in value (assuming the original values are > 0.
5. we use `as_tibble()` to remove the rownames and finally `arrange`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(variables, "red")) %>% 
  mutate(names = paste0(names, row_number()),
         value = value*-1) %>% 
  bind_rows(df) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(str_detect(variables, "red") &
                          value > 0, 0, value)) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  arrange(names)
```

```
  names   variables           value
  <chr>   <chr>               <dbl>
1 colour  c(red, blue)            0
2 colour  c(yellow, blue)        32
3 colour  c(green, red, pink)     0
4 colour  c(pink, purple)        14
5 colour1 c(red, blue)          -10
6 colour2 c(green, red, pink)   -81
7 shape   c(circle, triangle)     5
8 shape   c(rectangle)           31
```

```
structure(list(names = c("colour", "colour", "colour", "colour", 
"shape", "shape"), variables = c("c(red, blue)", "c(yellow, blue)", 
"c(green, red, pink)", "c(pink, purple)", "c(circle, triangle)", 
"c(rectangle)"), value = c(10L, 32L, 81L, 14L, 5L, 31L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Hi TarJae! Thank you so so much for your quick reply, much appreciate it. :) Could you please perhaps help me further with this query? The solution you shared works if it's just 'colour' we are trying to work with, but I'm trying to make this loop over all categories under names - each have different target values. Let's say this table has 1000+ rows with different name categories (eg colour, shape, clothes type, clothes size etc..) And the target value may not be unique - eg. values for for 'clothes type' may contain 'red dress'. How wold you modify the code to cater these? Thanks